# SVG image not supported in android 9 version

Tags: android

SVG images not support for android 9 version.I am tried Glide,Picasso and sharp library to show SVG image into image view. It work for till android 8 version,but android 9 has the problem to show image.

Comment: You are supposed to convert svg to Vectors using Android Studio and some attributes of SVG aren't available on Android.

Comment: Did you test it on a different version? If so share the screenshots of the different versions and share the vector drawable.

Answer (score 2):

To use SVG on Android,

[image]

Then Select Local file and choose the path[image]

Thus the svg will be converted to vector which is supported by android studio.

Comment: am asking get from webservice for svg image not supported android 9 version?

Comment: Sorry then, android won't support svg